# php clean urls using regex

Tags: php, regex, search, clean-urls

i am trying to convert these urls

```
localhost/list/data/?search=keyword
localhost/list/data?search=keyword
```

to

```
localhost/list/data/search/keyword
```

i used this expression

```
(.+)(\?|\/\?)([a-z0-9_-]+)=([a-z0-9_-]+)
```

the problem is suppose that the user searches for another keyword

```
localhost/list/data/search/keyword/?search=anotherkeyword
localhost/list/data/search/keyword?search=anotherkeyword
```

it becomes like this

```
localhost/list/data/search/keyword/search/anotherkeyword
```

how can make it like this

```
localhost/list/data/search/anotherkeyword
```

where in it replaces the previous **search/keyword** in the url

Answer (score 0):

Its a little more complicated than just regex. The best approach is a combination of server side scripting, and htaccess. I wrote up an answer for a very similar question not to long ago. As well as use this solution in a handful of sites I develop.

[PHP dynamic DB page rewrite URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022509/php-dynamic-db-page-rewrite-url/11022705#11022705)

Ill save the time from rewriting the post I made on the above link and just let you use that as your guide, hope it helps